# Update Move Count (Counter) - Towers of Hanoi - C program

Tags: c, recursion

I wrote this C program for moving a number of disks (n) from peg A to peg C while tracing the path. However, I do not know how/where to put a count call/ increment so that the total number of moves is kept track of and printed out at the end. Any advice would be appreciated. (Originally I had it printing in the TOH function, which did not work so I removed the printf(..) line)
I changed the variables so it would increase readability; however, the count output is way off. For number of plates = 3, count = 239. For number of plates 4, count = 130,431

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int TOH(int,char,char,char);
 int main()
 {
   int n;
   printf("\nEnter number of plates:");
   scanf("%d",&n);
    int c = TOH(n,'A','C','B');
    printf("\n");
    printf("Total number of moves = %d \n ", c);
  return 0;
  }
  int TOH(int n,char first,char third,char second)
 {
   int count;
  if(n>0){
     count=TOH(n-1, first, second, third);
     printf("Move disk %d from peg %c to peg %c\n", n, first, third);
     count++;
     count+= TOH(n-1, second, third, first);
     }
  return count;
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return the value of the `count` from your function to the `main`. For this you have to call it from `main` as

```
int c = TOH(n,'A','C','B');
```

and change return type of your function to `int`.

```
int TOH(int,char,char,char);
```

I changed your function a little bit:

```
int TOH(int n,char x,char y,char z)
{
   int count = 0;
   if(n>0){
       count = TOH(n-1, x, z, y);
       printf("\nMove disk %d from peg %c to peg %c\n", n, x, y);
       count++;
       count += TOH(n-1, z, y, x) ;
   }
   return count;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to recommend this strategy you should also explain how `TOH` needs to handle `count` internally, since it is no longer as simple as incrementing it at the right point.

Comment: @Zack Pretty trivial fiddling in my opinion: `return TOH(n-1, x, y, z) + TOH(n-1, z, y, x) + 1;`

Comment: @Zack; In fact this will do what OP wants.

Comment: @haccks It will, but *not by itself*, so your answer is incomplete.  Taylor points at the right approach, but there is still a hurdle which may be insurmountable for a beginner.

Comment: @Zack; He is using recursion and I presume that he is not that much beginner.

Comment: So where exactly am i placing the TOH(n-1,x,y,z) + TOH(n-1, z, y,x) +1. I understand that this is the total amount of recursion calls, but where to place it is my main concern

Comment: @haccks See what I mean?

Comment: @Fish Well you should store the count from the first call of TOH, then do the printf, then return that first count + 1 + the return from the second call of TOH. By the way, the first call of TOH should actually be `TOH(n-1, x, z, y)`, not `TOH(n-1, x, y, z)`

Comment: @Zack; I understand now what you are trying to say :). Updating my answer.

Comment: @haccks, I edited my C code up above. the count output is way off for n>2.

Comment: @Fish; If you look at my answer carefully then you will find that I intialised `count` to `0` in the beginning otherwise it invokes **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be to make `count` a global variable, i.e.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void TOH(int,char,char,char);
unsigned int count;
/* what you have, but remove the declaration of `count` from `TOH` */
```

You can then access `count` from both `TOH` and `main` and it will be the same variable.

You probably also want to increment `count` only once in `TOH` (right after the `printf`, I think).

Comment: Come on, let's not teach a c newcomer that global variables are good solutions to problems...

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter It is the *simplest* solution to this problem, which makes it a good approach for a toy program like this one.  Teaching new programmers to avoid globals Just Because is just as bad practice as teaching them to avoid `goto` Just Because.

Comment: Why is it simplest? The other solution seems simpler to me. Also, it's bad practice for a reason. It would mean he could only call the function once from main, or would have to remember to reset the count every time before calling it. Global variables limit the portability and self-contained-ness of functions, there's no reason to use one when it offers no advantage.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter Maybe more precisely "it is the smallest change to the OP's code that will make it work".  Anyway, yes, you and I immediately see all the potential problems that come up if this were a piece of a larger application, but (a) *it isn't*, (b) how is the OP ever to learn *why* global variables are a problem if they are kept away from them by dogma?  (If I had written this homework assignment I would probably require the students to code it both ways and then make a list of reasons to choose one or the other.)